# Ambiguous reference when getter/setter have different visibilities

Tags: actionscript-3, visibility, setter, getter

The following code raises an **ambiguous reference** to `value` at compile time:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var _value : Number = 0.;

    public  function get value() : Number           { return _value; }
    private function set value(v : Number) : void   { _value = v; }

    public function Main() : void
    {
        value = 42.;
    }
}
```

I suspect some kind of bug in the compiler, though I didn't actually read the ECMA standard.

Before someone asks those questions:

- Private setters do make sense.
- The ambiguity also exists with custom namespaces (which is the problem I'm facing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed a bug in the compiler, and it is [listed in the bugs](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-1829). its stated that its an oversite of the developers and wont be fixed any time soon.

if you are needing to specifically run a function to set privately (rather than just assign the value, in which case you can leave out the setter function completely and itll run) then you will have to run a seperate function as Sandro said.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a limitation of AS3. You could create a private function called setValue() or if your set on having a setter you might be able to get away with this, although it's not very pretty.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var __value :Number = 0;

        public function Main(): void {
            _value = 42;
        }
        public function get value():Number {
            return __value;
        }
        private function set _value(v:Number):void {
            __value = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. Thanks for comforting the idea.

Comment: Another solution is to manually disambiguate with `private::value` when possible.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the tip. I didn't know you could disambiguate the variable that way.