# Private setter not accessible when the class is instantiated (ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've made a test class with a private setter and a public getter. The original setter set more values but I've minimized the code for simplicity.

```
package Lib
{
    public class Test
    {
        private var _data:String;
        private var _isLoggedIn:Boolean;

        // isLoggedIn getter and setter
        public function get isLoggedIn():Boolean
        {
            return (_isLoggedIn == true && _data != null);
        }
        private function set isLoggedIn(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _isLoggedIn = value;
        }
        private function isLoggedInSet(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _isLoggedIn = value;
        }

        // constructor
        public function Test()
        {
            isLoggedIn = false;
            isLoggedInSet (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it compiles fine and I assume it works as expected. BUT as soon I try to use this in my main mxml:

```
import Lib.Test;
protected function fubar():void
{
    var test:Test = new Test(); 
}
```

I get this errors in Test.as (sic!):

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property isLoggedIn through a reference with  static type Lib:Test.
-1059: Property is read-only.
-isLoggedIn
```

Note that `isLoggedInSet (false);` works fine. Is this a bug or a feature? Feels like a bug... Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: This feels even more wrong, but it works:

```
private function get isLoggedIn():Boolean
{
    return (_isLoggedIn == true && _data != null);
}
public function get isLoggedInPublic():Boolean
{
    return isLoggedIn;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionScript - Read Only Property and Private Set Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465793/actionscript-read-only-property-and-private-set-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is a bug in the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509372/ambiguous-reference-when-getter-setter-have-different-visibilities).  Both the getter and the setter have to have the same visibility, unfortunately.  Use the variable directly if you need it to only be set from within the class, or a setter function with a different name (just like your `isLoggedInSet`).

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I've added the link to my answer.

Comment: Hm... Seem like a bit different bug, but it answers my question. I've added the bug here https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-4379